# How to show and hide textbox and label on the radio button selection in pyqt?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

This is my gui.If user select the **pass** radiobutton then marks(label) and textbox should be visible and as user select the **fail** radiobutton then marks(label) and textbox should not be visible.
This should be completely depend on radiobutton selection.How to do this in pyqt4 python?

GUI

[image]

Comment: which code? I seen the example of show and hide using button but i need it using radiobutton selection.

Comment: So you've seen it with usual buttons ? What was the code like ? The code you look for should look the same, with just one slot that checks 'Pass' radio button `isChecked`

Answer (score 0):

You will need something like:

```
# Connect radio button 
self.radio_pass.toggled.connect(passToggled)

def passToggled(self):

    """Hides markls label and qlineedit if radiobutton is not checked."""

     if not self.radio_pass.isChecked():
        self.lbl_marks.hide()
        self.qle_marks.hide()
```

`lbl_marks` is your label, `qle_marks` your marks field and `radio_pass` the radio button.